# Python 2.6 json error 400 and 401 when i trying to fetch from Ubiquity Unify API

Tags: python, json, ubiquity

I am trying to generate a voucher from Ubiquity UNIFY web portal.
It has a API, and there is some ideas to use this with PHP, but I would like to use Python 2.6 to generate.. (I can ofc ourse use other Python versions if this is a must)

My code is:

```
import urllib, json
import urllib2
import unifi
import os
import requests

def JsonLogin():
    payload = {"username" : "myuser","password" : "mypassword"}
    r = requests.post("https://ubnt.myserver.com:8443/api/login", data=payload, verify=False)
    print r

def JsonApi():
    payload = {"cmd":"create-voucher","minutes":1440,"n":1}
    r = requests.post("https://ubnt.myserver.com:8443/api/cmd/hotspot", data=payload, verify=False)
    print r

JsonLogin();
JsonApi();
```

My Result is:

```
   <Response [400]>
   <Response [401]>
```

Is there any logic why it returns 400, witch means error...
Is this because I sent invalid JSON or is this because the syntax or JSON tags are wrong?

Comment: Is the payload supposed to be a JSON string?  If so you will need to encode it with `json.dumps` as suggested by this [section in the `requests` quick start guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: good question.. i am not that "good" ..

Comment: https://github.com/malle-pietje/Unifi-API-browser/blob/master/phpapi/class.unifi.php#L1078-L1088'

Comment: the print r.text gives -    { "data" : [ ] , "meta" : { "msg" : "api.err.Invalid" , "rc" : "error"}}

Comment: 400 means bad request, and 401 means authorized failed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

payload= '{"username" : "myuser","password" : "mypassword", "strict":true}'
r = requests.post("https://ubnt.myserver.com:8443/api/login", data=payload, verify=False)
 print r

It should return 200

Then set someway the cookie value that the login returns into a variable 
 cookies=r.cookies

then

r = requests.post("https://ubnt.myserver.com:8443/api/cmd/hotspot", data=payload, verify=False, cookies=cookies)

I used it with GET and it works